# Apache POI - Export to Excel based on 2 Date Parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

Prior to this version I had a working solution (java,spring boot, Apache POI) which exported all data from the DB and wrote to a new excel file. Now I want to include a search parameter which will take 2 dates included in the URL, compare to the requestReceivedDate field and return all cases that are between the 2 search parameters. I get a 404 not found which suggests that the URL is not correct. I am unsure what the issue is here with the URL. Shared service and repo code to help understand how these classes interact.
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/piecases/download/28/09/2017/30/09/2019

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/piecases/download/{dateBefore}/{dateAfter}")
public String downloadExcel(Model model,
        @RequestParam(name = "dateBefore") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date dateBefore,
        @RequestParam(name = "dateAfter") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date dateAfter) {
    model.addAttribute("cases", outboundBankErrorService.exportAllCasesByDate(dateBefore, dateAfter));
    return "";
}
```

Service

```
public List<CaseData> exportAllCasesByDate(Date dateBefore, Date dateAfter) {
    return bankErrorCaseDataRepository.findByRequestReceivedDateBetween(dateBefore, dateAfter);
}
```

Repository

```
 @Repository
public interface CaseDataRepository extends JpaRepository<CaseData, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT cd FROM CaseData cd WHERE cd.requestReceivedDate BETWEEN :dateBefore AND :dateAfter")
    List<CaseData> findByRequestReceivedDateBetween(@Param("dateBefore") Date dateBefore,
            @Param("dateAfter") Date dateAfter);

}
```

Comment: The link to **your** localhost is useless for readers... Put the information in the question, please.

Comment: I shared to show how I was using the parameters in the URL.

Comment: OK, sorry, didn't get that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/piecases/download/28/09/2017/30/09/2019

would map to: `/piecases/download/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}/{f}` which is not what you intended hence the 404.
An easy fix would be to use a query string instead:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/piecases/download?datebefore=28/09/2017&dateAfter=30/09/2019

```
@GetMapping(value = "/piecases/download")
public String downloadExcel(Model model,
        @RequestParam(name = "dateBefore") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date dateBefore,
        @RequestParam(name = "dateAfter") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date dateAfter) {
    model.addAttribute("cases", outboundBankErrorService.exportAllCasesByDate(dateBefore, dateAfter));
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @FranciscoMateo now get a 400 error instead so it has resolved the above issue but I'll figure out what's causing the 400